# Tkinter reference methods and variables between classes

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am stuck at referencing methods and variables between classes in `Tkinter`.

Here is an simple example, I have three different types of windows, which I would like to put into different `classes`.

In the `root` window, I can click the `button` to open the second window, where I can input something in to the `Text` widget.

Also in the 2nd window I want the `OK` button to read the content in the `Text` widget and `insert` the content into another `Text` widget into the 3rd window. And the `Cancel` button can close the 2nd window and show the `root` window again.

There is many bugs in the code, because I couldn't figure out how to make cross references between `classes` to access the `methods` and `variables`.

Could anyone help me to accomplish that? Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
    
    
    def main():
        """The main app function"""
        root = Tk()
        root_window = Root(root)
        return None
    
    
    class Root:
    
        def __init__(self, root):
            # Main root window configration
            self.root = root
            self.root.geometry("200x100")
            
            self.btn_ok = Button(self.root, text="Open new window",
                                 command=NewWindow)
            self.btn_ok.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
        def hide(self):
            """Hide the root window."""
            self.root.withdraw()
    
        def show(self):
            """Show the root window from the hide status"""
            self.root.update()
            self.root.deiconify()
    
        def onClosing(self, window):
            window.destroy()
            self.show()
    
    
    class NewWindow:
        
        def __init__(self):
    
            Root.hide()
        
            self.new_window = Toplevel()
    
            lbl = Label(self.new_window, text="Input here:")
            lbl.pack(padx=10, pady=(10, 0), anchor=W)
    
            # Create a scrolledtext widget.
            self.new_content = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(
                                    self.new_window, wrap=WORD,
                                    )
    
            self.new_content.pack(padx=10, expand=True, fill=BOTH, anchor=W)
    
    
            # Respond to the 'Cancel' button.
            btn_cancel = Button(self.new_window, text="Cancel", width=10,
                                command=lambda: Root.onClosing(self.new_window))
            btn_cancel.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=RIGHT)
    
            # Add 'OK' button to read sequence
            self.btn_ok = Button(self.new_window, text="OK", width=10,
                                 command=WorkingWindow)
            self.btn_ok.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=RIGHT)
    
        def readContent(self):
            self.content = self.new_content.get(1.0, END)
            self.new_window.destroy()
            workwindow = WorkingWindow()
    
    
    class WorkingWindow:
    
        def __init__(self):
    
            self.work_window = Toplevel()
            self.work_content = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.work_window, wrap=WORD, font=("Courier New", 11))
            self.work_content.pack(padx=10, expand=True, fill=BOTH, anchor=W)
            self.work_content.insert(1.0, Root.content)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there all you have to do is pass the instance of Root class to other class you are calling

Here is the corrected code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
    
    
def main():
        """The main app function"""
        root = Tk()
        root_window = Root(root)
        root.mainloop()
    
    
class Root:
    
        def __init__(self, root):
            # Main root window configration
            self.root = root
            self.root.geometry("200x100")
            
            self.btn_ok = Button(self.root, text="Open new window",
                                 command=lambda :NewWindow(self))
            self.btn_ok.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
        def hide(self):
            """Hide the root window."""
            self.root.withdraw()
    
        def show(self):
            """Show the root window from the hide status"""
            self.root.update()
            self.root.deiconify()
    
        def onClosing(self, window):
            window.destroy()
            self.show()
    
class NewWindow:
        
        def __init__(self, parent):
    
            parent.hide()
        
            self.new_window = Toplevel()
    
            lbl = Label(self.new_window, text="Input here:")
            lbl.pack(padx=10, pady=(10, 0), anchor=W)
    
            # Create a scrolledtext widget.
            self.new_content = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(
                                    self.new_window, wrap=WORD,
                                    )
    
            self.new_content.pack(padx=10, expand=True, fill=BOTH, anchor=W)
    
    
            # Respond to the 'Cancel' button.
            btn_cancel = Button(self.new_window, text="Cancel", width=10,
                                command=lambda: parent.onClosing(self.new_window))
            btn_cancel.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=RIGHT)
    
            # Add 'OK' button to read sequence
            self.btn_ok = Button(self.new_window, text="OK", width=10,
                                 command=self.readContent)
            self.btn_ok.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=RIGHT)
    
        def readContent(self):
            self.content = self.new_content.get(1.0, END)
            
            self.new_window.destroy()
            workwindow = WorkingWindow(self)
            
    
    
class WorkingWindow:
    
        def __init__(self, parent):
    
            self.work_window = Toplevel()
            self.work_content = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.work_window, wrap=WORD, font=("Courier New", 11))
            self.work_content.pack(padx=10, expand=True, fill=BOTH, anchor=W)
            self.work_content.insert(1.0, parent.content)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Great solution!! I guess I haven't grab the concept of 'parent' in Tkinter. But your modification clears me a lot. Thanks much!

Comment: Another thing still confuses me. It seems like, by using `parent`, I can only access `Root` class from `NewWindow` class; and access `NewWindow` class from the `WorkingWindow` class. What if I want to access `Root` class from the `WorkingWindow` class, for example, I want to show the `self.root` window again when I close the `self.workWindow`, by calling the `onClosing()` method in the `Root` class. `self.work_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: Root.onClosing(self.work_window))`  How should I achieve this?

Comment: @ZhenhuaXu quickest way to achieve that might be to make an instance variable and assign it to the parent. for eg:- in `NewWindow` class constructor assigns `self.parent=parent` and now from `WorkingWindow` class you can access the `Root` class by calling `parent.parent`

Comment: Yes, that works!   In this way, it works fine when there is not too many code. But when the classes got complicated, this layer by layer reference will seem tedious and inconvenient. Is there an easier way to directly access a class from any class? I have seen some posts using controller, I understand the concept but have trouble using it. Would you be able to explain how to use controller using our current example code? Thanks!

Comment: @ZhenhuaXu I think it would be better if you make a separate post.

Comment: Made a new post asking this question. [Find it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299070/tkinter-cross-reference-class-and-variables-using-controller)