# Tkinter cross reference class and variables using controller?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, reference, controller

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66272406/tkinter-reference-methods-and-variables-between-classes), I asked how to reference methods and variables between classes in Tkinter. And @JacksonPro  provided a nice solution using `parent` like the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
    
    
def main():
        """The main app function"""
        root = Tk()
        root_window = Root(root)
        root.mainloop()
    
    
class Root:
    
        def __init__(self, root):
            # Main root window configration
            self.root = root
            self.root.geometry("200x100")
            
            self.btn_ok = Button(self.root, text="Open new window",
                                 command=lambda :NewWindow(self))
            self.btn_ok.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
        def hide(self):
            """Hide the root window."""
            self.root.withdraw()
    
        def show(self):
            """Show the root window from the hide status"""
            self.root.update()
            self.root.deiconify()
    
        def onClosing(self, window):
            window.destroy()
            self.show()
    
class NewWindow:
        
        def __init__(self, parent):
    
            self.parent = parent
            parent.hide()
        
            self.new_window = Toplevel()
    
            lbl = Label(self.new_window, text="Input here:")
            lbl.pack(padx=10, pady=(10, 0), anchor=W)
    
            # Create a scrolledtext widget.
            self.new_content = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(
                                    self.new_window, wrap=WORD,
                                    )
    
            self.new_content.pack(padx=10, expand=True, fill=BOTH, anchor=W)
    
    
            # Respond to the 'Cancel' button.
            btn_cancel = Button(self.new_window, text="Cancel", width=10,
                                command=lambda: parent.onClosing(self.new_window))
            btn_cancel.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=RIGHT)
    
            # Add 'OK' button to read sequence
            self.btn_ok = Button(self.new_window, text="OK", width=10,
                                 command=self.readContent)
            self.btn_ok.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=RIGHT)
    
        def readContent(self):
            self.content = self.new_content.get(1.0, END)
            
            self.new_window.destroy()
            workwindow = WorkingWindow(self)
            
    
    
class WorkingWindow:
    
        def __init__(self, parent):

            self.parent = parent
            self.work_window = Toplevel()
            self.work_content = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.work_window, wrap=WORD, font=("Courier New", 11))
            self.work_content.pack(padx=10, expand=True, fill=BOTH, anchor=W)
            self.work_content.insert(1.0, parent.content)
            self.work_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",
                             lambda: parent.parent.onClosing(self.work_window))
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

However, it seems like this approach only allows you to reference between class layer by layer, using a lot of `parent`. Like this in the code：

```
self.work_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: parent.parent.onClosing(self.work_window))
```

It would be very inconvenient and confusing when the classes are accumulating in the application. So I was wondering how to achieve the goal of accessing any method or variable in any class from anywhere using `controller`? I have seen posts on `controller`, but still confusing on how to use it, for example, in this case. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have found it to be clearer to pass the main (controller)  window downward to any lower level widgets e.g. new window would be def __init__(self,parent,controller,....  This controller variable could be passed on to lower classes in your hierarchy.  It separates the frame/window from the controller function, and even allows you to use a separate class as the controller.  That said, the controller is the controller.  You should not try to communicate directly with neighbors.  Instead define functions in the controller to handle the communication.

Comment: Your post would be clearer if you provided a link to a post which you are looking at and explain what about the post is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Since each tk object knows what their master is, use a recursive function call to find the parent that is an instance of `Tk`.

Below is a contrived example that contains a few different frames and a button. The `find_tkroot` function will move up through the hierarchy to find the `Tk` instance. In this case, it just uses it to set the title of the root window.

```
from tkinter import *

def find_tkroot(widget):
    try:
        if widget.__class__.__name__ == 'Tk':
            return widget
        else:
            return find_tkroot(widget.master)
    except RecursionError as err:
        print(err)
        print("Got lost at {0}".format(widget))

root = Tk()
frm1 = Frame(root)
frm2 = Frame(frm1)
frm1.grid()
frm2.grid()
btnClose = Button(frm2,text="Close",command=lambda: find_tkroot(btnClose).title('Set Me'))
btnClose.grid()

print(find_tkroot(frm2))
```

You could extent this to find a parent of a specific class name if you create your own classes.

```
def find_parent_matching(widget, class_name):
    print("Checking: ", widget)
    try:
        if widget.__class__.__name__ == class_name:
            return widget
        else:
            return find_tkroot(widget.master)
    except RecursionError as err:
        print(err)
        print("Got lost at {0}".format(widget))
```

Which takes a widget name as a second parameter, for example `find_parent_matching(widget,'MyCustomClass')`